# Merge Arrays and Remove Duplicates Swift & Firebase

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've got an application that retrieves data from a Firebase Database. My issue is that whenever the data is updated, it retrieves a whole new array of the data (and appends it at the end of the array). For example, if my array is :

`["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]`

And I attempt to remove D (in a tableView; when I swipe to delete, it removes the entry from Firebase), the array becomes

`["A", "B", "C", "E", "A", "B", "C", "E"]`

I have tried using the array `removeAll()` method before returning the array, but my tableView refreshes before it can finish; so it crashes saying index out of range. Is there anyway that I can create a second array in my database update function, and then call a merge method with my main array, and prevent adding duplicates every time? Thanks!

Code:

```
    self.conditionRef.observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

        self.stocks.removeAll()
        self.stockObjects.removeAll() 

        if snapshot.value is NSNull {
            print("nothing found")
            self.title = "No Results"
        }
        else {

            for i in snapshot.children {
                self.stocks.append(i.key)
            }
            print(self.stocks)

        }

        for stock in self.stocks {

            let stockSnapshot = self.conditionRef.child(stock)
            stockSnapshot.observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in



                if snapshot.value is NSNull {
                    print("nothing found")
                } else {


                    let price = snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("price").value as! String

                    let volume = snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("volume").value as! String

                    let stockObj = StockObject(name: stock, price: price, volume: volume)

                    self.stockObjects.append(stockObj)

                    print(stockObj.name)
                    print(stockObj.price)
                    print(stockObj.volume)

                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }

    })
```

UPDATE: I have solved my issue by converting my StockObject class to equatable and adding this function to the class:

```
 func == (lhs: StockObject, rhs: StockObject) -> Bool {
     return lhs.name == rhs.name
 }
```

Then, in the code I have above, I have replaced the line where I append to the array with this:

```
if self.stockObjects.contains(stockObj) == false {
    self.stockObjects.append(stockObj)
}
```

So far, everything works as it should. Any ideas on where this might crash?

Comment: You can merge arrays removing duplicates: `let c = Array(Set(a+b)).sorted()` An `Array(Set(anyArray))` always contains unique values so you can set Table dataSource to be like that.

Comment: @K.Nimo `Set` will only work if the order doesn't matter, which is unlikely in this case

Comment: @AaronBrager, Array has `sorted()` method.

Comment: @K.Nimo It could work if the models can determine their correct order. But they may not be able to if the correct order is determined on Firebase and not determinable by the model properties.

Comment: @AaronBrager, Yes, I agree with you.

Comment: @K.Nimo I was thinking something along the lines of using Set, but I accidentally made my question more basic than what it is. My array is actually a set of Objects (thought it would function the same as strings), where the Object has name and price. When I try to call Set it says cannot invoke initializer for type 'Set<_>' with an argument list of type '([CustomObject])'

Comment: Can you add your code where your setting your array after getting firebase data? I'm pretty sure I've had this exact problem and fixed it with one line of code.

Comment: @NSGangster just added it, thanks!

Comment: It does seem that how u solved the problem is a good safe gaurd. But may be symptom relief for what is causing the problem. The `removeAll()` function should be clearing your array and then only one for every item in your database should be added. I would suggest also try setting your array to an empty array. And double check to make sure something in your deleting of the database it isn't creating more objects on your database. Because while your code will safegaurd you from creating duplicates on the app side, Your database could have 20 of the same object and you not know about it!

Comment: @NSGangster good catch! Luckily, firebase doesn't seem to allow duplicate entries, but if I change the data from the Firebase Console, my app won't update, so I need to find a workaround for that. What's weird is that I looked at my class variables after the crash, and my stocks array is correct, but my stockObjects array is empty, even though I am calling them right after each other. 

Actually, I just fixed it by adding an Else statement to my contains function, where I set the index that contains the object to the new one. It all works, but seems very sketchy haha